# WPF MediaElement not streaming while on lower bandwidth connection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-6.0, mediaelement

I am working on WPF application running on .NET 6. Recently I encountered really strange  behaviour with MediaElement control.

I have the backend service able to stream files, for instance videos. I want to embed a video player within the frontend (WPF) application with the streaming capability. I have already achieved this with [libvlcsharp](https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp) although it doesn't meet all the requirements (mainly performance) and is being left out as side/additional feature. I want to be able to stream multiple videos at the same time (in the same window as well) similar to youtube/instagram reels. For that purpose I decided to go with MediaElement control. I succesfully embeded multiple MediaElements but there are some issues.

I have confirmed that MediaElement doesn't work properly while on low bandwidth connection. While I am on my optic fiber 900+ Mbps connection everything works fine, the videos are being streamed with no issues. While on lower bandwidth (tested on two cellular networks with <20 Mbps) the **Player is not loading/buffering/starting** at all.

I could not find any related documentation.
I believe it is not related to the file format and file size as I tested the same files on both networks. Files ranging from a few KB to a few GB.

User control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Peernet.Browser.WPF.Controls.EmbededPluginsControl">
   <Grid>
      <MediaElement Grid.Row="0" Name="Player" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" Stretch="Fill" />
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class EmbededPluginsControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FileProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("File", typeof(ApiFile),
    typeof(EmbededPluginsControl), null);

    public EmbededPluginsControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += EmbededPluginsControl_Loaded;
    }

    private void EmbededPluginsControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var settings = App.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(ISettingsManager)) as ISettingsManager;
        Player.Source = GetFileSource(settings, File);
    }

    public ApiFile File
    {
        get => (ApiFile)GetValue(FileProperty);
        set => SetValue(FileProperty, value);
    }

    public static Uri GetFileSource(ISettingsManager settingsManager, ApiFile file)
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            ["hash"] = Convert.ToHexString(file.Hash),
            ["node"] = Convert.ToHexString(file.NodeId),
            ["format"] = "14",
            ["k"] = settingsManager.ApiKey
        };

        var uriBase = $"{settingsManager.ApiUrl}/file/view";

        var requestMessage = HttpHelper.PrepareMessage(uriBase, HttpMethod.Get, parameters, null);
        return requestMessage.RequestUri;
    }
}
```

By default all Players are stopped, there is no issue such as that I try to run all at once and it is killing the network or something. There are buttons dedicated for Player as simple as:

```
            <Image x:Name="PlayButton" Height="20" Width="20" MouseDown="OnMouseDownPlayMedia" Margin="5">
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource PlayImage}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource PlayImage_MouseOver}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
```

and

```
    void OnMouseDownPlayMedia(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
    {
        Player.Play();
    }
```

I also don't manipulate programatically the Player stream, buffering, etc.

Do I have to reset the stream while connection drops or something? I am running out of ideas.

Comment: Media element is media player. The control is just a thin wrapper around media player.

Comment: The performance in wpf is apparently worse because of a clock mismatch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make MediaElement work as good as AxWindowsMediaPlayer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39122344/how-to-make-mediaelement-work-as-good-as-axwindowsmediaplayer)

Comment: @Andy thanks for comments. I think my case is different. The MediaElement doesn't start the stream or buffering at all. It looks more like IO-Bound related issue rather than CPU-Bound.